# MS ACCESS Error in insert into X(...) select ... from A union select ... from B

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

Access 2000 (mdb base).
Stametement:

```
insert into full_join_DR(y,m,ds,rs,b) 
  select r.y, r.m, d.summa as ds , r.summa as rs , d.summa - r.summa as b 
  from r left join d on r.y=d.y and r.m=d.m 
     union 
  select d.y, d.m, d.summa, r.summa , d.summa - r.summa 
  from d left join r on r.y=d.y and r.m=d.m
```

> Error:Syntax error

though inner select statement works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the union query as a subquery:

```sql
insert into full_join_DR(y,m,ds,rs,b) 
select t.y, t.m, t.ds, t.rs, t.b
from
  (select r.y, r.m, d.summa as ds, r.summa as rs, d.summa - r.summa as b 
  from r left join d on r.y=d.y and r.m=d.m 
     union 
  select d.y, d.m, d.summa, r.summa, d.summa - r.summa 
  from d left join r on r.y=d.y and r.m=d.m) as t
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works.
But why it did not work,

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so. Union queries must be "isolated" to work in action queries.